# Android app works perfectly in Debug mode but Freeze up in Run mode Java

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. My app works fine when Debugging but always freezes when in run mode or my phone is unplugged. LogCat is also not giving any errors.
Any help please..

These are the logs from the run mode. And it always freezes at this point

```
05/15 09:17:30: Launching 'KENTEN' on HUAWEI DUB-LX1.
Connected to process 21935 on device 'huawei-dub_lx1-58K6R19124030060'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/HwFLClassLoader: get used feature list :/feature/used-list failed!
    USE_FEATURE_LIST had not init! 
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#256
    apicache path=/storage/261A-3884 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#0
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/261A-3884 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#0
E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@7ad92c9
W/zygote64: Agent attach failed (result=2) : Unable to dlopen /data/data/com.astromyllc.kenten/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.astromyllc.kenten/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so" not found
E/ActivityThread: Attaching agent failed: /data/data/com.astromyllc.kenten/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so=/data/local/tmp/perfd/agent.config
I/zygote64: Starting profile saver IsSaveProfileNow end.
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21935 SIG: 9
Install successfully finished in 58 s 24 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.astromyllc.kenten/com.astromyllc.kenten.Splash" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 22115 on device 'huawei-dub_lx1-58K6R19124030060'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/HwFLClassLoader: get used feature list :/feature/used-list failed!
    USE_FEATURE_LIST had not init! 
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#256
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/261A-3884 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#0
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/261A-3884 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#0
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@42410eb
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
W/tromyllc.kenten: type=1400 audit(0.0:3300): avc: denied { write } for name="hwlog_exception" dev="tmpfs" ino=13921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hw_exception_dev:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
V/ActivityThread: Skipping new config:{1.0 620mcc1mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h733dp 320dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1520) nonFullScreen=0 suim:1 s.7}, config:{1.0 620mcc1mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h733dp 320dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1520) nonFullScreen=0 suim:1 s.7} for app:com.astromyllc.kenten
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
V/HwPolicyFactory: : success to get AllImpl object and return....
V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to get AllImpl object and return....
W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
I/Splash: On Create Begins
W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:48 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:49
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 49
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
D/HwGalleryCacheManagerImpl: mIsEffect:false
W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 67, previously 69
    ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 5678, previously 5679
W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0f0009, context : com.astromyllc.kenten.Splash@1694331, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.astromyllc.kenten, 1:1084982656950:android:ce8e16cf4612abd6838b17
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 40013
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.astromyllc.kenten
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Persisting first open: 1621070309248
V/FA: App measurement setting deferred collection: false
V/FA: Checking service availability
    Service available
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
V/FA: Session started, time: 5016503
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
    After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote64: Thread[3,tid=22128,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x78c7aa8400,peer=0x1ccc2ca0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/zygote64: Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'
```

THIS IS THE LOGCAT LOGS

```
2021-05-15 09:18:28.732 22115-22115/? W/main: type=1400 audit(0.0:3294): avc: denied { create } for name="cgroup.procs" scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:cgroup:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-05-15 09:18:28.743 22115-22115/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-05-15 09:18:28.900 22115-22115/? D/ActivityThread: Attach thread to application
2021-05-15 09:18:29.038 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten D/HwFLClassLoader: get used feature list :/feature/used-list failed!
2021-05-15 09:18:29.038 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten D/HwFLClassLoader: USE_FEATURE_LIST had not init! 
2021-05-15 09:18:29.085 22115-22169/com.astromyllc.kenten I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#256
2021-05-15 09:18:29.086 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2021-05-15 09:18:29.086 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/MultiDex: Installing application
2021-05-15 09:18:29.086 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2021-05-15 09:18:29.086 22115-22169/com.astromyllc.kenten I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/261A-3884 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#256
2021-05-15 09:18:29.091 22115-22169/com.astromyllc.kenten I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#0
2021-05-15 09:18:29.091 22115-22169/com.astromyllc.kenten I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/261A-3884 state=mounted key=com.astromyllc.kenten#10389#0
2021-05-15 09:18:29.156 22115-22196/com.astromyllc.kenten E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@42410eb
2021-05-15 09:18:29.168 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2021-05-15 09:18:29.251 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-05-15 09:18:29.258 22115-22169/com.astromyllc.kenten E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2021-05-15 09:18:29.259 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
2021-05-15 09:18:29.262 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten W/tromyllc.kenten: type=1400 audit(0.0:3300): avc: denied { write } for name="hwlog_exception" dev="tmpfs" ino=13921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hw_exception_dev:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
2021-05-15 09:18:29.292 22115-22205/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2021-05-15 09:18:29.346 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
2021-05-15 09:18:29.351 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/Splash: On Create Begins
2021-05-15 09:18:29.375 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2021-05-15 09:18:29.416 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:48 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:49
2021-05-15 09:18:29.416 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 49
2021-05-15 09:18:29.440 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten D/HwGalleryCacheManagerImpl: mIsEffect:false
2021-05-15 09:18:29.476 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 67, previously 69
2021-05-15 09:18:29.476 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 5678, previously 5679
2021-05-15 09:18:29.542 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
2021-05-15 09:18:29.561 22115-22208/com.astromyllc.kenten W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2021-05-15 09:18:29.634 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0f0009, context : com.astromyllc.kenten.Splash@1694331, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2021-05-15 09:18:29.689 22115-22115/com.astromyllc.kenten I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
2021-05-15 09:18:29.845 22115-22264/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 40013
2021-05-15 09:18:29.845 22115-22264/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2021-05-15 09:18:29.846 22115-22264/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.astromyllc.kenten
2021-05-15 09:18:29.846 22115-22264/com.astromyllc.kenten D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2021-05-15 09:18:30.074 22115-22264/com.astromyllc.kenten I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2021-05-15 09:18:30.489 22115-22127/com.astromyllc.kenten I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
2021-05-15 09:18:30.489 22115-22127/com.astromyllc.kenten I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
2021-05-15 09:18:30.489 22115-22127/com.astromyllc.kenten I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2021-05-15 09:18:40.001 22115-22128/com.astromyllc.kenten I/zygote64: Thread[3,tid=22128,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x78c7aa8400,peer=0x1ccc2ca0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2021-05-15 09:18:40.073 22115-22128/com.astromyllc.kenten I/zygote64: Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'
2021-05-15 09:19:21.041 22115-22174/com.astromyllc.kenten I/zygote64: Starting profile saver IsSaveProfileNow end.
```

Comment: Please try to install in another device and check once. Also please give little more details about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just started creating an Android mobile app using Kotlin in Android Studio. I encountered the same problem. Mine was due to using tab views. What happened is that my onload tab needs to fetch some data from my SQLite DB which is taking time thus the view is timing out and causing the app to hang or crash. Same issue was encountered when sliding or navigating going to a tab with heavy database query.

Comment: Hi Jon, so how did you solve it? Am using Tabs as well. And I just added SQLITE to my app. Before adding the SQLITE it all worked fine. My aim was to make it faster by fetching the data it needs from my server to the local SQLite and minimize calls over the internet when using it

Comment: I included another tab which contains static image and text only and set it as the home tab and then added a page limit: `viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = tabLayout.tabCount`

Answer (score -1):

Check if you set `proguard` in `build.gradle`

I guess your `build.gradle(.app)` have this setting like below `release` > `minifyEnabled true`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ...
    }
}
```

and you have to set `progaurd` for your code. or `minifyEnabled false` if you don't need `progaurd`

Comment: Hi liveAnyaway, am not using progaurd in my app and do not have minifyEnabled in my build.gradle

Comment: Hi liveAnyaway, am not using progaurd in my app and do not have minifyEnabled in my build.gradle

Comment: Try multidex setting in `build.gradle`

Comment: Proguard can only minimize the app (and cause other problems) but it can not help if an app is freezing.